# Use Redux store as input for Post API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I built an input interface in React and stored the data in a Redux state.

Then, I created a new action for a Post API call. If the "data" parameter is a constant (that I created as a test), everything works fine.

**In reality, I'd like to use a key from the Redux state as the data parameter.**

In the example, I'm getting an error because props are not defined.
Does it makes sense to connect this action to the state? If yes, how to do it? Thanks a lot!

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const show_query_action = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(show_query_started_action());
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/show_query',
      data: this.props.reducer_components
    })
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(show_query_success_action(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(show_query_failure_action(err.message));
      });
  };
};

const show_query_started_action = () => ({
  type: 'ADD_SHOW_QUERY_STARTED'
});

const show_query_success_action = todo => ({
  type: 'ADD_SHOW_QUERY_SUCCESS',
  payload: {
    ...todo
  }
});

const show_query_failure_action = error => ({
  type: 'ADD_SHOW_QUERY_FAILURE',
  payload: {
    error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to be callable with different parameters from a React component you can put the data parameter as a parameter to your action creator:

```
export const show_query_action = (data) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(show_query_started_action());
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/show_query',
      data: data
    })
```

This is also easily testable. If you only call this action with parameters from the redux store, you can use the second parameter from redux-thunk (wich i presume you are using here):

```
export const show_query_action = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const data = getState().data; -> you would specify in wich part of the state your data lives, this is just an example
    dispatch(show_query_started_action());
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/show_query',
      data: data
    })
```

Hope this helps.